# how to check Color in fullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

hello i want to check if color has color css('#FF7F50') :
show an alert message i try but no succes can i find someone help

```
        function GenerateCalender(events) {
            $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
            $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                contentHeight: 400,
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                },
                eventLimit: true,
                eventColor: '#FF7F50',

                events: events,
```

this my function

```
                /******Check Color *******/
                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    if (calEvent.eventColor == "#FF7F50") {
                      return  alert("tttt");
                    }
```

this my controller :

```
  public JsonResult Check(string ThemeColor)
    {
        return Json(db.Events.Any(c => c.ThemeColor == "NULL"));
    }
```

this my scripts :

```
     eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                    //return $.ajax({
                    //    type: "POST",
                    //    url: "/Home/Check",
                    //    data: "ThemeColor",

                    //    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    //    dataType: "json",
                    //    success: function (response) {
                    //        if (response) {
                    //            alert("tttt");

                    //        }
                    //        else {
                    //            alert("tttt222222");


                    //        }

                    //    }


                    //});
```

how i can call the eventcolor to chec if color is NULL or not

Answer (score 0):

There's no such property as `eventColor` on an event. The list of recognised properties, including colour ones, is here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object .

It seems you confused it with [eventColor](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventColor) which is a global option you can set on the whole calendar, not a specific event.

As per that documentation. the equivalent property on an event object is `color`, so you can amend your code as follows and it should work:

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
  if (calEvent.color == "#FF7F50") {
    return  alert("tttt");
  }
```

---

P.S. `return alert` doesn't make much sense - an `alert` doesn't generate a value to be returned. I think you can simplify it to just `alert("tttt");`. Returning a value from `eventClick` wouldn't have any purpose anyway - fullCalendar isn't expecting the callback to provide any kind of response.

Comment: thank you very much but your solutions work but i have database and when the color is NULL and color in view example red the function not workk for me

Comment: so i added a function ajax to check if color is NULL or not but i don't know what i write in calEvent

Comment: i edit my post to understand me if color have NULL in database alert me message if not show me the other alert

Comment: sorry I don't understand why you need to check in the database whether any events have a null colour or not? That part does not make sense to me. Please explain more clearly what your goal is.